# Stripe : how to limit subscriptions to N reccurencies?

Tags: stripe-payments

I would like my client to monthly subscribe to a product (30 days billing period), with a maximum of 3 years : so 3 * 12 = 36 reccurencies. **So after 3 years, his subscription is automatically canceled.**

I could find that feature in Paypal, but did not find that feature in the stripe.

regards

Answer (score 1):

When creating a Subscription, if you calculate the exact time in the future that you want it to cancel then you can provide that timestamp via the `cancel_at` parameter [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/update#update_subscription-cancel_at). However, if you use that approach and don't set `cancel_at` to the exact end of a billing period, then the final invoice will have a prorated amount.

You can also use Subscription Schedules to achieve this, which are objects that allow you to schedule changes that will be made to your Subscriptions in the future. You could use these to schedule a future phase to set [`cancel_at_period_end`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/object#subscription_object-cancel_at_period_end) to true for your Subscription, causing it to automatically cancel at the end of that billing period. When creating the Subscription Schedule, you can use [`phases.iterations`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscription_schedules/create#create_subscription_schedule-phases-iterations) to easily set the duration of the phases to match your needs.

You can read more about Subscription Schedules here:
https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/subscription-schedules